# Properly Verifying HTML POST against Database

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I have a site that I am building using Django 1.9 and python 2.7. On my site, I have a checkout page where users select values from 1. `select` 2. `radio` 3. `checkbox` fields.

Each value selected has a specific dollar amount attached in the `value` part of the input parameter. I have created items for each possible selection inside my database and want to verify that the information was not edited by using a browsers code editor before submitting the final cost value.

Here is what one of my options in a select menu looks like:

```
<option name="apartment"  value="600" id="4p4rtm3nt">Apartment Building</option>
```

I have an object inside my DB (MySQL) with the `value`, `name`, and `id` all matching this option.

What would be the most productive/safest way to verify that this information has not been changed when calculating my cost of all items?

---

**Personal idea**

I am thinking of just pulling the id, name, & value from the POST and then making sure they all match the object inside my DB. This just seems extensive and inefficient...

How have some of y'all done it? I tried looking at some websites with checkout pages and can't seem to figure out their way of doing things.

*P.S. I am not using Django forms*

Comment: The best way to do this is to *use Django forms*. That's what they're for.

Comment: Funny you say that, I was reading up on those after posting this...

Comment: I agree about Django forms. They are very very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use the `id` property to **identify** the values the client has chosen. With the `id` from the POST object, you can simple lookup the records and calculate the cost from those results. The client can't browser edit the values in your database.

If you are really concerned with the performance implications (premature optimization is the root of all evil), just make sure your table is indexed on `id`. Django already does this for you.

Comment: I read somewhere I can only get the `name` from a POST request... I can pull the ID as well?

Comment: Ok I misunderstood what you are doing. In a POST request, the `POST` is a dictionary-like object that with the input tag's `name` attribute as the key and the  `value` attribute as the value. 

What I would recommend is change the HTML to set the record's `id` to the value attribute, then you can get that from the `POST` object by the input name and then do what I recommended originally.

Comment: Thank you for your help, sound advice